# How to get last command run without using `!!`?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to alias `_!` to `sudo` the last command, but I'm running into roadblocks. `!!` doesn't seem to work in my `.zshrc` file, and sed has given me repeated problems. I tried using the following command, and several variations of it, but to no avail.

`history | tail -1 | sed -e 's/[^0-9\*\ ]+/\0/g'`

However, this still interpreted the piped input as a file, instead of a string of text. I also tried a variation using `awk`:

`history | tail -1 | awk '{ gsub("/[^0-9\*\ ]+", "") ; system( "echo" $1 ) }'`

I'm sure I'm just having some trouble putting the commands in correctly, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Q: What platform are you on? Linux, or "something else"? Is there any reason you're not using bash (and .bashrc)?

Comment: @FoggyDay: zsh is a more powerful shell than bash.

Comment: @FoggyDay I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I simply prefer `zsh` to `bash` due to the power and flexibility it adds. However, if I remember correctly, they're mostly compatible, with the exception of some enhancements `zsh` implements.

Comment: If I wanted to `sudo` the previous command, I'd just type `sudo !!`, or Ctrl-P, Ctrl-A, `sudo`, space, Enter.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's more of a convenience thing. I'm currently doing that, and it is supremely easy, but for additional convenience, I want to `alias _!='sudo !!'`. I just need to figure out what I can use in place of `!!`, since it doesn't look like it works non-interactively. This isn't a necessity, but a nice thing to have nonetheless.

Comment: Don't you use sudo !! only when you accidentally run something that needs sudo without? Does that happen THAT often that you need a shortcut for it?

Comment: I agree that it seems like a security risk to alias a sudo.

Comment: @MightyPork It's not a necessity, but it's as much a thing that I want to see if it's possible as it is an actual useful tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `fc` built-in to access the history programmatically.  For example, I believe this will behave as you wish:

```
alias _!='fc -e "sed -i -e \"s/^/sudo /\""'
```

With no arguments, `fc` (short for "fix command") fires up `$EDITOR` on your previous command and runs the result of your editing. You can specify a different editor with the `-e` option; here, I'm specifying a non-interactive one in the form of a `sed` command that will insert `sudo` in front of the command line.

The command assumes GNU sed. As written, it will also work with the version that ships on modern BSD/macOS, but by way of a hackcident: it treats the `-e` as an argument to `-i` instead of a new option. Since the `-e` is optional with only one expression, this works fine, but it means that `sed` makes a backup of the temp file with `-e` on the end, which will hang around after the command completes. You can make that cleaner by using this alternative version on those systems:

```
alias _!='fc -e "sed -i \"\" -e \"s/^/sudo /\""'
```

(That *won't* work with GNU sed, which sees the empty string argument as a filename to operate on...)

On older systems, a more portable solution could use `ed`:

```
alias _!="fc -e 'ed -s <<<$'\''s/^/sudo /\nw\nq'\'"
```

You can often get away with something simpler, like `sudo $(fc -ln -1)` (`-l` = list commands, `-n` = without numbers, `-1` = only the last command), but in general you will run into quoting issues, since the command is output by `fc` the way it was typed:

```
% touch '/etc/foo bar'
touch: /etc/foo bar: Permission denied
% sudo $(fc -ln -1)
touch: '/etc/foo: No such file or directory
```

None of the above is limited to zsh, btw; `fc` dates to the original version of ksh, so it will also work in bash, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This `fc` command will always give most recently executed command in `zsh` and in `bash`:

```
fc -ln -1
```

As per `help fc`:

```
 -l (letter el) list lines instead of editing
 -n omit line numbers when listing
```

`-1` (minus one) gets the just executed command.

Answer (score 1):

Found a amazing widget to sudo:

```
sudo-command-line() {
    [[ -z $BUFFER ]] && zle up-history
    [[ $BUFFER != sudo\ * ]] && {
      typeset -a bufs
      bufs=(${(z)BUFFER})
      if (( $+aliases[$bufs[1]] )); then
        bufs[1]=$aliases[$bufs[1]]
      fi
      bufs=(sudo $bufs)
      BUFFER=$bufs
    }
    zle end-of-line
}
zle -N sudo-command-line
bindkey "\e\e" sudo-command-line
```

Author:[lilydjwg](http://lilydjwg.is-programmer.com/)

---

**The following is the way to run the last command in command:**

---

`fc -ln -1` is the simplest way, but one problem, when run something with some spaces at the beginning of the command, this command won't shown up in history, **anything based on history won't work properly**.

So we need ZLE(Zsh Line Editor) to store the command manually.

```
Store_Your_Command () {
    if [[ -z $BUFFER ]]
    then
        # If nothing input, just clear the screen
        zle clear-screen
    else
        zle accept-line
        # Remember the last command, useful in some alias
        # Add space at the beginning of a command, this command wont
        # show up in history, so use variables to store the command
        LAST_COMMAND=$CURRENT_COMMAND
        CURRENT_COMMAND=$BUFFER
    fi
}
# Create a user-defined widget
zle -N Store_Your_Command
# Bind it to the **Enter** key
bindkey "^M" Store_Your_Command
```

Then whenever we press enter to run a command, this command will be stored in $CURRENT_COMMAND, and the last command will be stored in $LAST_COMMAND.

Want to run the last command? Just run `eval $LAST_COMMAND`, you can also put it to your alias.

---

When some alias in the last command, zsh wont run the last command correctly, so we need to expand our alias: when we input an alias, replace the alias to the original command/content, with help of the builtin zle: _expand_alias.

First, delete the widget we just added.
Add those to your .zshrc:

```
# When input space, expand alias -----------------------------------{{{
expand_alias_space () {
    zle _expand_alias
    zle self-insert
}
zle -N expand_alias_space
bindkey " " expand_alias_space
# }}}
# When input enter, expand alias -----------------------------------{{{
expand_alias_enter () {
    if [[ -z $BUFFER ]]
    then
        zle clear-screen
    else
        zle _expand_alias
        zle accept-line
        # Remember the last command, useful in some alias
        # Add space at the beginning of a command, this command won't
        # show up in history, so use variables to store the command
        LAST_COMMAND=$CURRENT_COMMAND
        CURRENT_COMMAND=$BUFFER
    fi
}
zle -N expand_alias_enter
bindkey "^M" expand_alias_enter
# }}}
```

Now we can expand alias to the original command/content by press `Space` key or just press `Enter` key to run the command, and use `eval $LAST_COMMAND` to run the last command without any problems.

---

But it will call another problem when run a command use `eval $LAST_COMMAND` twice:

`zsh: job table full or recursion limit exceeded`

We need to replace `eval $LAST_COMMAND` to the real command, because `$LAST_COMMAND` always change.
We write a function run the last command like this

```
# Echo the last command 
fun()
{
    # The command we need to run in this function
    CURRENT_COMMAND="echo \[`echo $LAST_COMMAND`\]"
    # run the command 
    eval $CURRENT_COMMAND
}
```

The command stored in `$CURRENT_COMMAND` wont change like `eval $LAST_COMMAND` does.
problem sloved.

---

No more problem I hope

Answer (score 0):

If I want `.` to be the alias for last command,

```
lastcmd() {
    # start climbing back in history, checking for alias
    n=-1
    lc=$(fc -ln $n $n)
    # "." is checked because I have aliased lastcmd to "."
    while [ "$lc" = "lastcmd" ] || [ "$lc" = "." ]
    do
        n=$(( $n - 1 ))             
        lc=$(fc -ln $n $n)      
    done
    eval ${lc}
}

alias .=lastcmd
```

This is pretty simple and works well for me. Replace the second condition in `while` with whatever alias you end up using.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.zshrc` --

```
func preexec() {
  export LAST_COMMAND="$1"
}
```